# When I kill the app background services is not working in Ionic Cordova app

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

When I kill the App, Background Services are not working in the Ionic Cordova app.

I am using this plugin:  @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.

Environment:

Ionic-4, Cordova-8, Android Device: Redmi note 5 pro, Android OS: Oreo

This is my code.

```
let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
  desiredAccuracy: 10,
  stationaryRadius: 0,
  distanceFilter: 0,
  notificationTitle: 'Background Tracking',
  notificationText: 'Enabled',
  debug: true,
  interval: 10000,
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  startOnBoot: true,
  url: '  http://192.168.43.182:8000/geolocation',
  httpHeaders: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },

  postTemplate: {
    latitude: this.latitude,
    longitude: this.longitude,
    deviceId : '8234832',
    userId: 'eeehimanshu22@gmail.com'
  }

};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then(() => {
  this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
    console.log("loc: "+location)
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.latitude = location.latitude;
      this.longitude = location.longitude;
    })
  })
})

this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The plugin is working as intended, background mode means when the app is still active but in another tab, not the current active app. When you quit the app there's no way to keep tracking geo location that I know off.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Even though app is kiiled i am getting the background geolocation data but not able to post to Http server in background mode. In notification area i can see the background is running.